# angularjs converts null to string "null"

Tags: angularjs

I am posting an object by http. If $scope variable is null, http form send it as string "null" instead of null. This cause validation problems.

I found a solution as below but it is not elegant way to solve it. Why is this happening and do you have any suggestion to fix this in better way?

```
    var data = {
        suiteApt: $scope.suiteApt === null ? '' : $scope.suiteApt,
    };
```

EDIT:
**Request Header:**
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

**FormData:**
suiteApt=null

**In APi Controller**, suiteApt is defined as string in model class
public string SuiteApt { get; set; }

**Debugger** show as below in model
SuiteApt = "null"

Comment: Please show us the code where you are posting the object, and I would suggest looking at the request (in your browser's Networking tab) to see what is actually being sent. If you can track that down, I would ask that you add that to the question as well.

Comment: var data = {
        suiteApt: $scope.suiteApt || ''
 };

Comment: I have edit my code.. @eustatos your suggestion looks pretty good. I was thinking may be there is even better solution.